# How to set each controller a default url or requestMapping in springMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

For example:the class which is a controller has a requestMapping `@RequestMapping("/company")` ,and it has a method named "index".
In this case,how can i input a url like '/company' or '/company/' and enter the method named "index"?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. One of the example, to use `@RequestMapping` on method and specify request type:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFoos() {
    return "Get some Foos";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/foos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String postFoos() {
    return "Post some Foos";
}
```

[More](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@RequestMapping` with multiple paths like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/company", "/company/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

(It has `String[]` as `value` parameter)